# Setting the Publisher in Installed Updates for a .MSP patch

Tags: windows-installer, patch

We're building a patch for a product we've deployed with MSI. When I install my patch, the Installed Updates panel looks like this:

[image: Updates window]

(redacted the product and company names)

The product name and patch name are populated correctly, but the Version and Publisher columns are blank, and we can't find a way to populate them. (See the red box in the screenshot)

We can see that Microsoft have managed to at least populate the publisher, if not the version, on some of their updates. This seems a little random - when I scroll through the list here, some updates have publishers, some have versions, some have both, some have neither.

Because of this inconsistency, we don't consider it a massive deal if we can't populate these values, but if there's a way we'll consider it.